# Может ли в таблице PostgresSQL не быть первичного ключа?

Tags: postgresql

Можно ли считать ключ первичным если он не помечен как primary key?

И корректно ли создавать такую таблицу где не один атрибут не помечен этим модификатором?

Comment: Про постгре точно сказать не могу, но в mysql, по идее, создать такую таблицу можно, только внутренние механизмы будут все равно искусственный первичный ключ прикручивать к таблице.
Подозреваю, что в postgre аналогично дела обстоят.

Comment: И имейте ввиду, что большинство таблиц в БД как то связаны с другими. Большинство СУБД позволяют ссылаться на таблицу внешними ключами (foreign key) только смотрящими на первичный ключ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Можно ли считать ключ первичным если он не помечен как primary key?

Если он ограничен уникальным индексом и не может быть null (другими словами, однозначно указывает на запись) - условно можно

> И корректно ли создавать такую таблицу где не один атрибут не помечен этим модификатором?

Наличие первичного ключа - свойство сущности, а не таблицы, поэтому да, теоретически может быть ситуация, где первичного ключа и вовсе не существует.

Answer (score 1):

Наличие первичного ключа не является обязательным условием при создании таблицы, равно как и наличие любых других ограничений данных. Однако работать с единичными строками такой таблицы будет затруднительно, а в случае если требование уникальности строк не будет обеспечено ни в каком виде то невозможно. Вы получите неуправляемый массив данных. С такой ситуацией особенно часто приходилось сталкиваться при загрузке результатов ручного мыслетворчества любителей Excel.

ЗЫ:

Недавно был [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1490519/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2-postgresql-%D0%B2-pgadmin-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2/1490594#comment2672281_1490594) по заблокированным таблицам в которые не может добавлять данные Grid pgAdmin как раз по этой причине, отсутствие первичного ключа и невозможность идентификации отдельных записей.