# Почему в postgresql в pgAdmin при создании таблицы, столбцы создаются заблокированные

Tags: postgresql

Установил себе postgresql, установил pgAdmin, но при создании таблицы через pgAdmin, столбцы заблокированы? В чем может быть проблема?[image: Скрин pgAdmin]

Comment: А Вы закомиттили создание таблицы?

Comment: Нет, а как это сделать?

Comment: Так это же вывод результата запроса, разве нет? Почему там должны быть столбцы разблокированы?

Comment: Нет, я еще ничего не запрашивал. Я создал таблицу со столбцами, после чего хотел добавить в столбцы тестовую информацию, но не могу так как столбцы заблокированы, информацию хотел добавить не через SQL запрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы создали таблицу без первичного ключа. Редактировать данные в таких таблицах средствами pgAdmin не получится. Добавьте поле id сделайте его первичным ключом и замок пропадет.

```
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS mytable
    ADD COLUMN id serial NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS mytable
    ADD CONSTRAINT mytable_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Да не за что, посмотрите бобра, сам на него я так и не переехал, хотя он у меня установлен. Но в современной среде DBA RU принято считать что настоящий мусчина курит капитанский табак и использует бобра https://dbeaver.io/download/